C# Maui iOS GetAwaiter Operation is not supported on this platform
I'm trying to use the GoogleAPI Roads library to snap to road.
The call is async:
GoogleMaps.Roads.SnapToRoad.QueryAsync(request).GetAwaiter();
But when I run the code I get the error 'Operation is not supported on this platform'.
The original code was:
var response = await GoogleMaps.Roads.SnapToRoad.QueryAsync(request).Result;
But that required the void that makes that call to be async, so that just moves the problem to earlier in the callstack.
I cannot use OnCompleted either, as that requires a call to GetAwaiter first.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.
The device is running iOS 16.7.4, Xcode 15.2 and Visual Studio 17.8.6
EDIT: Updated with async task function
Still getting the same error on:
var response = await GoogleMaps.Roads.SnapToRoad.QueryAsync(request);

This is what I got now:
public static async Task<List<Position>> snapToRoad(List<Position> gpsPos)
{
    List<Position> result = new List<Position>();
    List<List<Position>> subLists = ListExtensions.ChunkBy<Position>(gpsPos, 100);
    foreach (List<Position> gPos in subLists)
    {
        Coordinate[] requestPath = gPos
        .Select(geo => new Coordinate((double)geo.Latitude, (double)geo.Longitude))
        .ToArray();

        SnapToRoadsRequest request = new SnapToRoadsRequest
        {
            Key = MAPS_KEY,
            Path = requestPath
        };
        var response = await GoogleMaps.Roads.SnapToRoad.QueryAsync(request);
        foreach (SnappedPoint sp in response.SnappedPoints)
        {
            result.Add(new Position(sp.Location.Latitude, sp.Location.Longitude));
        }
    }

    return result;
}

It's calld by a new thread that is started by a button click event:
async void btnSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread trd = new Thread(async () =>
    {
        var snapped = await MapUtils.snapToRoad(rawCordList);
    });
    trd.IsBackground = true;
    trd.Start();
}


you should just do var response = await GoogleMaps.Roads.SnapToRoad.QueryAsync(request);

Sorry to say, but it doesn't work.

What's the thread for? Try without it. It looks very out of place. Multithreading and asynchronous programming are related but different concepts that usually don't mix well.

I used Xamarin before and there I needed to run it in a thread, because you're not allowed to do network stuff on UI thread on Android. Maui is new for be, but uses the same base. I get the same error when I remove the thread.

Running long operations on the UI thread can lead to ANRs on Android, but that shouldn't happen with properly implemented async/await. Certain APIs actually need to run on the main/UI thread. This could be the case here, too. Unless an operation needs to explicitly run on the UI thread, you don't need to handle threads at all with the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP). If you need something to actually run on a thread pool thread for some reason, then you could do await Task.Run(async () => await MapUtils.snapToRoad(rawCordList));.

Okey, good to know. But I'm still stuck on this issue :(

Turns out, it was an issue with the library.
It tries to set a proxy and that is not supported by Maui on iOS at this time.
